# Will node-fibers break node domains?

Tags: node.js, node-fibers, node.js-domains

I'm currently using node-fibers to write synchronous server-side code.  I primarily do error handling through try-catch blocks, but there's always a possibility of an error occurring in external libraries or other little bits of asynchronous code.  I'm thinking about using the new domains functionality to try to route those errors to the correct request, and I'm wondering if anyone has tried using fibers and domains in the same app.

Depending on how domains work behind the scenes, I can imagine that fibers might break some of the assumptions used to associate async code with the correct domain.  Specifically, I'm worried domains might be doing something like the following to track contexts, which could break with fibers since fibers breaks the guarantee that a function will run to completion before any other code runs:

```
run_in_domain = function(to_run) {
    var old_domain = global_domain;
    global_domain = new_domain();
    try {
        to_run();
    } finally {
        global_domain = old_domain;
    }
}
```

Has anyone successfully or unsuccessfully tried to get fibers and domains to play together?

Answer (score 2):

I have written an article on how node domains work. [How Node Domains Work](http://www.lighthouselogic.com/node-js-domains-work/)

Basically they work similarly to `process.on('uncaughtException')`.

I can see that the author of node-fibers states that you can use `process.on('uncaughtException')` to handle exceptions with node-fibers so there shouldn't be an issue. See [Handling Uncaught Exceptions in a Fiber](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/66)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good article on domains.  Actually, reading it suggests the opposite conclusion, that fibers probably do mess domains up.  If you have code in between domain.enter() and domain.exit(), and you fiber.yield() somewhere in that code, I'm guessing the fiber you yield to will be running under that domain

Comment: Well, actually you could probably make them compatible by explicitly calling domain.enter() and domain.exit() when you switch fibers...

Comment: Don't forget to vote up my answer if it was useful or mark it as the best answer you have received. You can always change it later if a better answer comes in.